# Why scoped slots aren't working in vue js 3?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, v-for, slots

Why scoped slots aren't working in vue js 3 ?
I'm returning an object with v-for loop but the specialty field isn't visualized. I think I have an error. And the console is empty

> I'm expecting to return an array with v-for loop in vue js 3

```
// Child component
<tr v-for="person in crew" :key="person.id">
    <slot name="speciality-body" :crew="person.speciality"></slot>
    <td>{{person.tab}}</td>
    <td>{{person.fullname}}</td>
  </tr>
// Parent component
<CrewComponent :crew="crew.crew">
      <template #speciality-body="{speciality}">
        <td>{{speciality}}</td>
      </template>
    </CrewComponent>

// data. parent component
      crew: {
        crew: [
          {
            id: '1',
            speciality: 'fds'
          },
          {
            id: '2',
            speciality: 'fgh'
          }, ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There appears to be a typo in the property name. In the child component, you're binding the `person.speciality` to the `crew` property, but then in the parent component, you're trying to destructure it using the name `speciality`. This discrepancy in the property name would cause the value to be undefined.

You should change the child component's slot binding to match the name you're using in the parent component, like this:

Child Component:

```js
<tr v-for="person in crew" :key="person.id">
  <slot name="speciality-body" :speciality="person.speciality"></slot>
  <td>{{person.tab}}</td>
  <td>{{person.fullname}}</td>
</tr>
```

Parent Component and Data would remain the same. By making this change, the scoped slot should work correctly, and the `speciality` field should be visualized as expected.

If you still encounter issues, make sure that the rest of your code is consistent, and there's no other typographical or logical errors elsewhere in the components. Also, make sure that the data is correctly passed to the child component and that the `crew` prop is correctly defined in the child component.

Answer (score 0):

You should place the  element directly within the  element, and not as a direct child of the slot.
Here's the corrected version of the child component code:

```
<template>
    <tr v-for="person in crew" :key="person.id">
    <slot name="speciality-body" :crew="person.speciality">
        <td>{{ person.speciality }}</td>
    </slot>
    <td>{{ person.tab }}</td>
    <td>{{ person.fullname }}</td>
    </tr>
</template>
```

Here's the corrected version of the parent component code:

```
<CrewComponent :crew="crew.crew">
    <template #speciality-body="{ crew: speciality }">
    <td>{{ speciality }}</td>
    </template>
</CrewComponent>
```